# Google drive blocked access to a file in Colab

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, mount

I mounted my disk this way:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)
```

And I get access to all the files on the disk except for one: MyDataset.zip

If I try to copy it this way:

```
  copy_cmd = "/content/drive/My\ Drive/MyDataset.zip /content/MyDataset"
  !cp $copy_cmd
```

He writes an error:

> cp: error reading '/content/drive/My Drive/MyDataset.zip': Operation
>   canceled

If I try to download it via the colab file browser, it writes this error:

```
Error
Download failed
Could not fetch resource at https://colab.research.google.com/tun/m/gpu-t4-s-3l8lfafkvov1w/files/content/drive/My%20Drive/MyDataset.zip?authuser=0: 500 
FetchError: Could not fetch resource at https://colab.research.google.com/tun/m/gpu-t4-s-3l8lfafkvov1w/files/content/drive/My%20Drive/MyDataset.zip?authuser=0: 500 
    at Dz.Cz [as constructor] (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20200129-085600-RC01_292181754:910:76)
    at new Dz (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20200129-085600-RC01_292181754:910:293)
    at Aa.program_ (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20200129-085600-RC01_292181754:4070:158)
    at Ca (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20200129-085600-RC01_292181754:17:336)
    at Aa.next_ (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20200129-085600-RC01_292181754:15:474)
    at Ea.next (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20200129-085600-RC01_292181754:18:206)
    at b (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20200129-085600-RC01_292181754:26:268)
```

In this case, cp and file browser downloads work with any other files on the mounted disk.

Check this video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxTHf.jpg

What's wrong?

Comment: Can you download this file using the drive.google.com UI? One possibility is that Drive has classified this particular file as malware or containing malware, and thus transfers are prohibited.

Comment: How large is the file?

Comment: Google says that it could not check the archive for viruses, and I can download it.

Comment: The archive weighs 13.1 GB, but the problem should not be in this, on another disk there is a similar archive, it weighs 14 GB, and everything works, the problem is only on this disk.

Comment: Did you try to download the file manually from https://www.google.com/drive/? The other archive that weighs 14 GB - is it also a zip file? If you copy / move `MyDataset.zip` from the disc where it is now to the other disc with the 14 GB file - are you able to download it from there?

Comment: Yes, its zip, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved the problem, this is of course a crutch, but I had to split the archive into parts, change its format to rar (zip sucks with multi-volume and does not support modern encryption), and encrypt it, after that Google no longer blocks the transfer

The most interesting thing is that MyDataset.zip was downloaded 2 times, and then suddenly stopped, and even after 2 days, nothing changed, either in the code or in the archive.

Google can block unwanted files without warning.